Will the door fit in a rough opening only oversized 2 inches?
I have framed an opening for an exterior door that will be 32x80” and have therefore made the rough opening 34x82½”.
Every 32x80 door I’ve looked at at Lowe’s and Home Depot call for a rough opening width of 34¼”. With hindsight I should have checked this first.
Will it fit?
Is the extra 1/8” on either side just to allow more space for shimming the door etc?

What is the exact width of the jamb of this prehung door you have and what is the width of the rough opening? Measure these after small deviations from "perfect" plumb would be corrected with a baby sledge or even a framing hammer. Then try to fit it.

It will fit, assuming good carpentry on your part. If you've framed the opening plumb, level, and square, you theoretically need no gap. Any and all gap is to allow for a plumb, level, and square door frame installation using shims (and for future adjustment, should it be needed).
In short, it'll probably be fine, but it's a matter of your attention to detail. If you find that things aren't hunky-dory, pull the trimmer studs and rip them down to as small as 1" thick. Place the originally milled face toward the door opening for the best result when you reinstall them.
